# Distinction between 水果 and 果?

Tags: difference

On a certain website, the translation for fruit is 水果, but later on it tells me that it is also 果.
What is the distinction?

Comment: 果 is a fruit in a tree. In an abstract sense, it may also mean the fruit of labor, that is result: 结果, while 水果 is fruit in the concrete case.

Comment: it seems 果 can be considered a bound morpheme, cf. e.g. 汉语水平考试词典：果（名词性）［义 １］果实（fruit）～脯｜～酱｜红～｜鲜～｜～汁｜白～｜干～｜腰～（cashew nuts）｜野～｜这个地区生产各种水果｜这树已经开花结～了。［义２］事情发展的最后情况；结局（跟＂因＂相对）（result；consequence）：恶～｜苦～｜战～｜正～｜硕～累累｜自食其～｜这里边一定有因～关系｜搞清楚这件案子的前因～后。

Comment: Kiddy speak in some languages will even say 果果 or 果果儿

Answer (score 2):

果 is the abstraction of all kinds of "production of flower". It could be fruit, or nut.

水果 means "juicy fruit" literally, but it could be any "production of flowers" which tastes delicious, e.g banana. But usually, people don't call nuts 水果, but 坚果 instead.

Answer (score 1):

果 means fruit or result.

When the meaning is fruit, it equals to 水果.
When the meaning is result, it equals to 結果.

Both 水果 and 結果 can be abbreviated to 果. You had better look at the context.

Comment: some users doubt that 水果 and 结果 can generally always be abbreviated to 果, consider some examples in jukuu   水果, : 1.苹果和甜瓜是我喜爱的水果 2. 查尔斯除了水果什么也不吃.3.苹果和桔子是常见的水果。结果:1.如果说结果...2.用户研究中的调查结果...3....以及与预期结果之间的关系  suggesting that 果 may be considered a bound morpheme

Answer (score 0):

To get a better understanding of the comparison, I suggest you read more about the so-called single-syllable word or double-syllable words in the Chinese language.

Answer (score -2):

I'm chinese
“果”的多种含义
a．结出果实（水果：苹果，牛油果，香蕉，菠萝）；
b．事情的结局或成效（后果，结果）
c.果断（意思是很干脆）

Comment: Better to answer in English, especially when question is posted in English.

Comment: Please revamp your answer to include English translation.

Comment: The OP is asking for the difference between 水果 and 果.

Comment: A variety of meaning of the "fruit" a. bear fruit (fruit: apple, avocados, bananas, pineapple);B. what outcome or results (consequences, results) c. decisive (means simply)